# Laravel excel file edit using laravel excel

Tags: php, excel, laravel, csv, xlsx

I'm using maatwebsite/laravel-excel for excel import and export in my whole project but my current version of this package is 3.1. I need to edit the excel file this could be done by

```
Excel::load('file.csv', function($file) {

    // modify stuff

})->export('xlsx');
```

but this is only supported in version 2.1 and this is removed in 3.1 need to urgently do that how can i do that anyone have idea than please suggest me.

Answer (score 1):

You may do this by using the make:export command. see the quick start
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/

Comment: that's right but i have excel file in public folder and want to edit my excel file and then store it with same validation like old